# Best technique for counting laps?

Tags: ios, location, core-location

I'm making an app that needs to count laps for participants walking around a track. I thought that I could create a small geo-fence around the start point and have the OS let me know when the user entered it, however this doesn't seem to work as well as I was hoping. It seems that it isn't triggered reliably when the walker enters the fence or triggers in other areas around the track. (I'm testing without letting the device go to sleep at this time).

It also seems that the `locationManager:didExitRegion` method isn't called properly in my testing.

When the user taps the start button, the following method is called:

```
-(void)startLocationManager {
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && usingLocationManager) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        self.locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeFitness;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {      
    CLLocation *lastLocation = [locations lastObject];
    if (lastLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 10) {
        return;
    }

    // setup a geocode fence and count as user enters fence
    self.startRegion = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:lastLocation.coordinate radius:10 identifier:@"startPosition"];
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.startRegion];
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    lapCount++;
    [self updateLapDisplay];
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or can I not use `CoreLocation` in such a fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A geofence won't work well for this. You can't rely on it to trigger accurately or reliably. Use a location manager and its delegate in the normal way and trigger manually when the user comes to within 10 or 20 meters, then reset the trigger when they're 50 or 100 meters away from it.